# How to store and display tiles in 2D array of images?

Tags: java, arrays, image, swing, 2d

Today I started to do a 2D game using Java. I want to create a (dynamically, since the map is different each time I start it) map where there are Walls (W), Tiles (_), Enemy (E) and Player (P).

Map looks like this:

```
_ _ E P _ _ E _ _ _ 
P _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
_ _ _ T _ _ _ _ T _ 
_ W W W W W T _ _ _
```

Corresponding to this map I want for each field an image tile.

For example every tile field should have this [Tile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcSzC.png)

I am thinking having a 2D array of Images, but not sure how to store it and display it in `JFrame`.

```
private Image[][] imageMap;
for(int i = 0; i < dimensionX; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < dimensionY; j++)
    {
        if(charMap[i][j] == '_'). //string map is the map with characters
        {
            tiles[i][j] = ??? // store the image here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have all the right ideas. You should look into painting BufferedImages in Java.

Comment: Is anything drawn over the top of this map? If not, perhaps putting the images in a `GridLayout` would work best.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is it a good practice to duplicate image. Usually when I need to create map with tiles I will use buffered image and draw them in the end display it on JFrame (I don't recommended to display directly in JFrame because of poor performance).

So I recommed to create BufferedImage with the same size of JFrame:

```
BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(jframe.getSize());
```

Then create buffered image with tiles and put them a single tile:

```
BufferedImage[] tiles = new BufferedImage[5];
```

After that you can use your loop a draw in buffer:

```
buffer.drawImage(tiles[yourTileNumberInList], i*tileWidth, j*tileHeight, null);
```

At the end draw buffer in JFrame.

EDIT:
To draw in JFrame you need can use:

```
void drawInJFrame(JFrame jframe, BufferedImage buffer){
   Graphics2d g2d = (Graphics2D) jframe.getGraphics();
   g2d.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
   g2d.dispose();
}
```

When you want to use it in game and want to refresh you probably need to use loop and repaint JFrame.

```
while(true){
   // Yours game logic
   drawInJFrame(jframe, buffer);
}
```

If you don't want to use your thread on 100% you can limit game to some framerate.

```java
long startTime;
int fps = 60; // you can use another framerate 60 is for example

while(true){
   startTime = System.nanoTime();

   // Yours game logic 

   drawInJFrame(jframe, buffer);
   while (System.nanoTime() - startTime < 1000000000 / fps){
       try {
           Thread.sleep(0, 100 * 1000);  
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

It's propably the easiest way to make a game, but only for basic. This draw is execute by CPU so it's slow. You can look for any game library if you want to draw by GPU in easy way.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer! Can you enlighten me how to draw the buffer in Jframe?

Comment: Yes of course, I will edit my answer soon.

Comment: 1) `Graphics2d g2d = (Graphics2D) jframe.getGraphics();` Never call `getGraphics` on a GUI component. 2) It's generally not a good idea to custom paint a top level container like `JFrame`. Better to override the `paintComponent` method of a `JPanel` then add it to a frame (or another panel). 3) `Thread.sleep(0, 100 * 1000);` Don't block the EDT. Use a Swing `Timer` that calls an action listener which updates the game state, then calls `repaint()`.